# Surface integral question help.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

If $S$ is the surface of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$, compute the value of the surface integral
 $$\iint_S xz\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z + yz\,{\rm d}z\,{\rm d}x + x^2\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$$

Answer is given as zero

Comment: Are you aware of the [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)?

Comment: Have you tried using it for this problem?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am little confuse with notations dydz , dzdy and dxdy.Usually they have only dx,dy and dz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarification of the notation: what they're asking for is the surface integral of the vector-field given by
$$
F(x,y,z) = \langle xz, yz, x^2 \rangle
$$ 
over the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$.  If you use the divergence theorem, this amounts to calculating
$$
\iiint_V  (\nabla \cdot F)\,dx\,dy\,dz
$$

Comment: Now I have got it.I was just confused with those notations.Thank you.